# How to add more functions in the Helper class?

Tags: sails.js

According to Sails's document, helper class has a default 'fn' function. I cannot add function2 in it. Can you help me? Thankyou!

```
fn: async (inputs, exits) => {
  var result =  inputs.a + inputs.b;
  return exits.success(result);  
},
function2 : async (a, b) => {
  var result =  a + b;
  return exits.success(result);
},
```

Answer (score 0):

An helper and controllers(actions) can be writing using "actions2" syntax. I didn't found documentation about it's specification but according to documentation look like this: https://sailsjs.com/documentation/concepts/actions-and-controllers#?actions-2

**Alternatives to declare a function**

You could add a function outside helper or controllers(actions) like this.

```
function add(a, b) {
  return a + b;
}

module.exports = {

   friendlyName: 'Add - math operation for two numbers',
   description: 'Add two numbers',
   inputs: {
      a: {
        description: 'first value',
        required: true
      },
      b: {
        description: 'second value',
        required: true
      }
   },

   exits: {
   },

   fn: async function (inputs, exits) {
      // call to add function
      return exits.success({result: add(inputs.a, inputs.b)});
   }
};
```

Other options inside fn attribute

```
module.exports = {

   friendlyName: 'Add - math operation for two numbers',
   description: 'Add two numbers',
   inputs: {
      a: {
        description: 'first value',
        required: true
      },
      b: {
        description: 'second value',
        required: true
      }
   },

   exits: {
   },

   fn: async function (inputs, exits) {

      function add(a, b) {
        return a + b;
      }

      // call to add function
      return exits.success({result: add(inputs.a, inputs.b)});
   }
};
```

Answer (score 0):

To add a new helper to the helpers class, you would define it in a new file. In the console you can use `sails generate helper <desired extension>/<desired helper name>` This will give you a whole file with its own inputs, exits and fn. As an example I might have a set of helpers that work with a specific api called "formtastic". To create a helper that retrieves forms, in the terminal `sails generate helper formtastic/retrieve-forms`. This will create a new file that I can specify the inputs and exits and write all the needed code. Then when I want to call this helper elsewhere in back end code, I use camel case and dots for each folder extension, so: `sails.helpers.formtastic.retrieveForms()`